# C++/CLI Authenticate software through x509 certificate

Tags: .net, authentication, c++-cli, certificate, sslstream

My project is to create a client-server communication that uses the Secure Socket Layer (SSL) security protocol to authenticate the server and the client.

I used c++/cli language, SslStream class and i've created the certificates **to authenticate the hosts** of both parties ( client/server ).

It works fine but now the problem is that the client software must be installed in a lot of machines so i can't create a certificate for each machine.

How can i **authenticate the software** (not the host) using a x509 certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

This might HELP....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731899.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't help me alot.